# data.stackexchange throwing "All parameters must be set!" but no input field to do so?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, data-explorer

I'm trying to run the query [**How long until I get the generalist badge?**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/299/how-long-until-i-get-the-generalist-badge) without being logged in (because I couldn't, there seems to be a glitch on that page).

Not only the page looks weird but also when I click Run Query the page send me a file to download named **1** , which has these inside:

```
{"error":"All parameters must be set!"}
```

I can't find the text field to pass my user id. What's going on?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: I'm currently using Firefox 3.6.13 on Ubuntu Linux. I'll try with other browsers.

Comment: Funny, it works with konqueror 4.2.2. Maybe it's something they updated on the site yesterday during that maintenance.

Comment: Can't repro with Firefox 4.0b9pre 2010-12-19. Are you sure the page loaded completely?

Comment: @radp Yes, I'm sure. Take a look: http://i56.tinypic.com/rk0z9x.png

Comment: With konqueror 4.4.2 it works the first time I load the page, but if I refresh the page it breaks just like firefox (notice that this is not the same konqueror version I used for testing before). And by the way, this happens with other queries too.

Comment: No repro on Win7 FF 3.6.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving this as a no repro, this may be an issue in an old browser which will probably not be fixed